# Copy and Sync Database Changes to Entity Framework Models

Tags: database, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.0, sql-server-2016

We are using Entity Framework Code First, and have our models in C#.
One of our DBAs added an additional column, how do we migrate his change into our Net Core Project? Is there a command line to automatically sync this?

We know command line below will take a whole database and place into C#. We are only interested in small modified changes.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Comment: _We are using Entity Framework Code First_ - DBA shouldn't create columns in the database in the first place.

Comment: correct, undestand that, we are trying to accommodate different team members

Comment: Have you tried adding the column name to the model and generating the migration. Then change the migration by deleting the `AddColumn()` in the `public override void Up()` method of the migration?

Comment: You can manually add that column to Entity class. and then optionally to OnModelCreating() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all you've got. Using an existing database is an all or nothing affair. Either you manage your entities via code and migrate changes there back to your database, or you scaffold the entities from your database. In other words, a database change means you need to re-scaffold everything. There's no such thing as "code migration".

Alternatively, I suppose you could just manually modify the entity class. For simple changes like adding a new column, that's probably the best approach, as long as you take care to replicate the property exactly as it should be to match the column in the database.

**EDIT** (based on comments on question)

Okay, so if you're doing code-first, then no one should be manually touching the database ever. Period. You have to just make that a rule. If the DBA wants to make a change, he can communicate that to your team, where you can make the appropriate code change and hand back a SQL script to perform the migration. This is where DevOps comes into play. Your DBA should be part of your team and you all should be making decisions together. If you can't do that, this isn't going to work.

Comment: we will probably use technique like this below, to sync our projects,  the dba and sql reporting team also needs to create reports from database projects, https://www.sswug.org/bentaylor/editorials/database-projects-vs-entity-framework-database-migrations/

Comment: I also asked a question here, if you know,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209863/what-sql-server-2017-features-are-not-supported-in-entity-framework-core-code-fi

Answer (score 0):

1. Add column to the model.
2. Generate migration.
   Migration file `20180906120000_add_dba_column.cs` will be generated
3. Manually add new record about just created migration in table `_EFMigrationHistory`
   record: `MigrationId: 20180906120000_add_dba_column, ProductVersion: <copy from previous migration>`

If you want do it automatically, means you want combine two different approaches in same time.

I think there was a reason why EF team separated "EF Code First" and "EF Database first" approaches.

When you choose `EF Code first` approach, that means that source of truth is your application code.
If you want stick to have code-first approach, that mean you should train your DBA to write EF migrations.

Comment: @MarkThomas - "code-first" mean you have one source of truth  - "your code".  Train DBA write EF migrations